# SplitButton Locked - can't unlock. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I'm working with a split button in C# on VS2010 for an Outlook Add-In.  The code below is very basic testing code that  is baffling me.  I'm trying to add items to the splitbutton, but I'm told that the collection is read-only.  I can't seem to find how to change this, and it's driving me a little batty.

```
private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    string s;
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        s = r.Next().ToString();

        RibbonButton rc = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
        rc.Label = s;
        splitButton1.Items.Add(rc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At that point in your code, the Items property is read-only. You can only adjust the items collection:

- In the Visual Studio Properties Window
- In the Constructor of the Ribbon Class
- In the CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject method of the ThisAddin, ThisWorkbook, or ThisDocument class of your project.

[Setting Properties That Become Read-Only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608623.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, @Ritch.  I discovered that very early this morning after a good night's sleep and beer, but haven't had the chance to update the question.

Comment: Cool. It is an odd behaviour.